# Using 'pyenv activate' in a Dockerfile

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm trying to install and setup a pyenv within a Dockerfile (`FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel-ubuntu16.04`)

Here is the second half of the Dockerfile ( the first half is just installing dependencies ) :

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user && echo "user:resu" | chpasswd && adduser user sudo
USER user
WORKDIR /home/user

# install pyenv
RUN git clone git://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git .pyenv
ENV HOME  /home/user
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> .bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> .bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> .bashrc
RUN pyenv install 2.7.10

# install pyenv-virtualenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git .pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
RUN echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> .bashrc

# setup virtualenv
RUN pyenv virtualenv 2.7.10 foo
RUN /bin/bash -c '      source .bashrc && \
                        pyenv activate foo && \
                        pip install numpy && \
                        pip install nltk'
```

The Docker installation fails on the last line with :

```
Step 20 : RUN /bin/bash -c '    source .bashrc &&                       pyenv activate foo &&                      pip install numpy &&                    pip install nltk'
 ---> Running in 672826e55a40

Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

What is the problem here ? Is there a best-practice for setting up pyenvs with Docker ?

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but I use the “real” executable path in this situation. Instead of relying on `pyenv activate`, just replace `pip` with `$PYENV_ROOT/versions/foo/bin/pip`.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the need for virtualenvs within a container, but  others might disagree

Comment: people that might want to install any specific version of python on a specific dockerfile will disagree

Comment: @Kalessar did you ever solve/work around this?

Comment: I feel embarrassed to admit it, but I had the same issue, and in my case it was due to the fact that I was copy-pasting from two different stack overflow instructions, setting PYENV_ROOT and the path variables to some path (/opt/pyenv/) and the .bashrc stuff to another (~/.pyenv).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `source .bashrc` is ignored (and thus the default pyenv setup does not proceed) because the bashrc is often configured to [abort if not in the interactive mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041348/802810).

As a workaround, add `-i` interactive switch, or use another hack from the linked discussion. For this example, this would be:

```
bash -i -c "source ~/.bashrc && pyenv activate foo"
```

Alternatively, you can run the relevant commands setting up the pyenv (you will find them in your `.bashrc`) before the activation step. For me this would be:

```
bash -c "\
export PATH="/home/krassowski/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" &&\
eval "$(pyenv init -)" && \
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" && \
pyenv activate foo"
```